# Normal subgroups of finite index in infinite direct sum

Tags: group-theory

As you may know, in a finite direct product $\prod_{i\in I}S_i$ of finite nonabelian simple groups $S_i$, every normal subgroup is of the form $\prod_{i\in J,J\subseteq I}S_i$.

> Normal subgroups of finite index in infinite product $\prod_{i\in I}S_i$ (with $I$ infinite) are still of the same form?

Now we consider the direct sum $\oplus_{i\in I}S_i$ with $I$ infinite. The question is the same.

> What are normal subgroups of finite index in the infinite sum  $\oplus_{i\in I}S_i$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Direct sum for groups? Do you want to mean *free product* instead? Or *Abelian* groups?

Comment: @Berci, it is still a common name for the coproduct.

Comment: Ah, ok. So, it is free product.

Comment: Calling $\mathop{Supp} x = \{i\in I: x_i \ne 1\}$ the *support* of $x \in$ your infinite product/sum, take a look at the set $N_U$of all $x$ whose support is *not* an element of some fixed *non-principal* [ultrafilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) U on I. It's not too hard to show that $N_U$ is a normal subgroup. If all $S_i$ are isomorphic to each other, I think its index should be finite.

Comment: I don't think he  means the free product. He probably means the version of direct product in which only finitely many components of a group element are allowed to be nontrivial.